# Media keyboard buttons not working

Tags: unity, keyboard, shortcut-keys, media

When I press the up-volume, down-volume and mute buttons on my keyboard, nothing happens. The shortcuts option under keyboard in preferences recognizes the buttons, and org.gnome.plugins.media-keys has the right parameters, that is, XF86AudioRaiseVolume, etc. and they have been restored to defaults.
I'm using

> unity/xenial,now 7.4.0+16.04.20160415-0ubuntu1 amd64

on a Dell Inspiron N4110 laptop and I'm using Cairo-Dock. I have tried the solutions in
[Volume buttons not working in 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/461093/volume-buttons-not-working-in-14-04)
to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've sort of solved a similar issue using this https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2351990:

```
amixer set Master 1+
amixer set Master 1-
amixer -D pulse set Master toggle
```

It remains to bind the commands with the keys.  In my case, with OpenBox, I used the following in `.config/openbox/rc.xml`:

```
<keyboard>
  ...
  <keybind key="XF86AudioRaiseVolume">
    <action name="Execute">
      <command>amixer set Master 1+</command>
    </action>
  </keybind>
  <keybind key="XF86AudioLowerVolume">
    <action name="Execute">
      <command>amixer set Master 1-</command>
    </action>
  </keybind>
  <keybind key="XF86AudioMute">
    <action name="Execute">
      <command>amixer -D pulse set Master toggle</command>
    </action>
  </keybind>
</keyboard>
```

Comment: @guntbert Done I think.