# Volume buttons not working on lubuntu 16.04 fresh install

Tags: 16.04, sound, keyboard, lubuntu, lxde

When I press the volume keys (<kbd>F2</kbd> for -, <kbd>F3</kbd> for + and <kbd>F1</kbd> for mute with no need to press <kbd>Fn</kbd>)
I've tried the instructions from [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/461093/volume-buttons-not-working-in-14-04) to run:

```
gsettings reset org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys volume-up
gsettings reset org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys volume-down
gsettings reset org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys volume-mute
```

but It didn't work for me.

Is there an alternate way to fix this?

Answer (score 3):

Sorry for digging out an old post, but I have found a solution
In my case it was an issue with actions assigned to

```
XF86AudioLowerVolume
XF86AudioRaiseVolume
```

in the file

```
~/.config/openbox/lubuntu-rc.xml
```

Try to find a command that will work for lowering/raising volume from the terminal, in my case it is

```
amixer -D pulse sset Master 5%-
amixer -D pulse sset Master 5%+
```

so my entries in the file look like this (I left the default lubuntu entries commented out)

```
<keybind key="XF86AudioRaiseVolume">
<action name="Execute">
<!-- <command>amixer -q sset Master 3%+ unmute</command> -->
<command>amixer -D pulse sset Master 5%+</command>
</action>
</keybind>
<keybind key="XF86AudioLowerVolume">
<action name="Execute">
<!--     <command>amixer -q sset Master 3%- unmute</command> -->
<command>amixer -D pulse sset Master 5%-</command>
</action>
</keybind>
```

This whole section is inside the   element (as per https://wiki.lxde.org/en/LXDE:Questions#How_do_I_make_my_special_keyboard_buttons_.28mute.2C_volume.2C_screen_brightness_....29_work.3F )

You may need to logout/login or restart after making changes to the file.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Similarly, you could fix muting/unmuting by replacing `amixer -q sset Master toggle` with `mixer -D pulse sset Master toggle`

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I checked out the Sound settings and saw in the Output section that I had turned on the option 'Allow louder than 100%'. **Turning it off** resolved the problem for me.