# Volume buttons in keyboard not working in Ubuntu

Tags: 20.04, sound, keyboard, volume-control

I'm new to Linux and have installed Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. I'm in a Samsung notebook (NP550XDA) with a Portuguese Brazilian keyboard. It came with Windows 10. **That's my problem**: my keyboard volume up and down (<kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> and <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd> in my case) stopped working, but the mute and brightness keys still work. Not just that, but every time I turn on the notebook both the up and down keys work for just one time and like I was holding it, so the down button turn the volume down to zero then stop working and the up button turn it up to max. I don't think it's a problem of hardware because the <kbd>F7</kbd> and <kbd>F8</kbd> keys work just fine (I tested in `keyboard Shortcuts`) even after the volume keys stop working. I tried the following commands in terminal (as here https://askubuntu.com/a/468088) but didn't work:

```
gsettings reset org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys volume-up
gsettings reset org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys volume-down
```

I also see that it's not a shortcut problem because no shortcut is defined for any volume key, mute inclusive but this one works. Also when I press <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd> (my mute key) when defining a shortcut, it shows <kbd>Audio mute</kbd> which means that <kbd>Fn</kbd>+something is not a shortcut but an actual key.

I also tested this in the bootable Ubuntu USB which I used to install my Ubuntu version. Exactly the same problem had happened.

**Update**: I reinstalled my Windows 10 in a dual boot. The keys worked fine there but on Linux it's still not working.